# What is this extension/device on top of the wing of this ultralight?

Tags: aircraft-design, wing, ultralight

This a shot of the [Aero Synergie Papango](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aero_Synergie_Papango) ultralight, the succesor of the [Aero Synergie J300 Joker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aero_Synergie_J300_Joker).

[image]

The wings are more elaborate compared to its predecessor's and include on their top two additional extensions/devices.

What are they? Any aerodynamic role or just for aesthetic sake?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Those are [wing fences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wing_fence) and they prevent airflow perpendicular to the direction of travel. This isolates the portions of the wing and allows the inner wing to stall independently of the outer wing.

Since the wing uses flaps, the inner portion will create more lift and stall (separation of airflow on the upper wing leading to loss of lift) at a lower angle of attack. Wing fences prevent this stall from extending over the outer part with the ailerons, so the airplane will stay controllable in a stall and will not suddenly drop one wing.

Comment: Why is that a benefit?

Comment: @GrahamBorland it is more beneficial for swept wings, but because the isobars don't need to be in line along the whole wing you can get away with more

Comment: I must be missing something - wings can stall? I thought engines stalled... How can part of a wing stall when the rest of the craft hasn't? Aren't they all travelling at the same speed? Or is that something that kind of deserves its own question...

Comment: @corsiKa when a wing loses lift that is called stalling, and the different aerodynamic properties of where the flaps and ailerons are is enough to provide different stall characteristics

Comment: @corsiKa: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stall_%28fluid_mechanics%29

Comment: @corsiKa: Most wings are slightly twisted to make the stall progress gradually from the middle outward, keeping the ailerons effective longer and generally give pilot more time to react. And the wing fences slow the stall a bit more.